# How to align GUILayout elements

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, layout, alignment, editor

I am working on improving a transform inspector a bit and currently got stuck.

Is there a way to align these buttons to the right?

[image]

These are just two GUILayout buttons wrapped inside the horizontal group.

```
public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
    EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
    GUILayout.Button("World", EditorStyles.miniButtonLeft, GUILayout.Width(85));
    GUILayout.Button("Local", EditorStyles.miniButtonRight, GUILayout.Width(85));
    EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

    defaultEditor.OnInspectorGUI();
}
```

How can I position them to the right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can move your buttons to the right side by adding a flexible space in front of them:

```
public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
    EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
    GUILayout.FlexibleSpace();
    GUILayout.Button("World", EditorStyles.miniButtonLeft, GUILayout.Width(85));
    GUILayout.Button("Local", EditorStyles.miniButtonRight, GUILayout.Width(85));
    EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

    defaultEditor.OnInspectorGUI();
}
```

A flexible space simply eats all left over space within a layout group. If you have multiple flexible spaces, the space is equally distributed between them.

You might find some more details in my [IMGUI crash course](https://github.com/Bunny83/Unity-Articles/blob/master/IMGUI%20crash%20course.md).

Comment: @LW001 This is indeed the same course the Bunny83 posted. It's his own GitHub, and you could check the old link against web archive - so that's why I left "my" instead of "this" in his answer.

Comment: My bad @AgainPsychoX, I got names mixed up. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: Thanks for sorting out the link mess that Unity gave us. UA is dead and got replaced by "Unity Discussions". Though half the links do not properly redirect... This was the original question on UA / Discussions: https://discussions.unity.com/t/coroutines-ienumerator-not-working-as-expected/237287/3

Answer (score 1):

As alternative to [Bunny83's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63929877/7111561) in case you rather want to align the buttons with the left end of the other fields you instead just need to insert a space that has the same size as the prefix labels:

```
public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
    EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
    {
        GUILayout.Space(EditorGUIUtility.labelWidth);

        if(GUILayout.Button("World", EditorStyles.miniButtonLeft))
        {
            ...
        }

        if(GUILayout.Button("Local", EditorStyles.miniButtonRight))
        {
            ...
        }
    }
    EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();

    defaultEditor.OnInspectorGUI();
}
```